# Soft Floating Point Calculation Errors of Mono Runtime for MIPS

Tags: mono, runtime, mips, endianness

As we have been facing some issues with Mono project pertaining to the MIPS architecture, I wanted to ask a question.

We have Mediatek MT7628AN  mipsel-24kec processor(32 bit), and the example program written in C#  is to check the preciseness of floating-point calculations on target(MIPS)(no HFPU). The generated output by mcs is working fine on the host(x86), meaning that the floating point calculations are precise enough(2 pow 0=1...).

However, for the case of MIPS, the output is rather strange(2 pow 0=0 ...). After tracing the program execution in MIPS, the problem is two-sided. The first is math.pow(a,b) is always returning the power(b) instead of a^b. The second issue is about Console.WriteLine for double. This method cannot even print a double or float value properly. Instead, it is printing some random different numbers.

According to the tracing the program execution on the target(MIPS32 el),    System.OutOfMemoryException. Even after changing the cross toolchain option for MIPS(enable-decimal-float), the first issue has not been addressed.

Has someone tackled either issue or known smth related to it, that would be nice to share.

Comment: Mono is going away, and the whole .NET ecosystem is moving to .NET Core. You can find a specific MIPS64 port of .NET CLR for LoongArch64 is already available, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/projects/70#card-77692221 So if you want to support your MIPS32 you might get started from there.

Comment: Ok.  However, https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/mips/ according to the above documentation, the previous versions have support for MIPS32